# System printing to a certain index of a linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am working with java at the moment and I am trying to find out a way to stop printing to the console (for simplicity) after a certain index of a linkedList is reached. Any help explaining this would be much appreciated.
Below is my Node class used to create the list:

```
protected Integer data;
protected Node link;

public Node(Integer data, Node link) {
    this.data = data;
    this.link = link;
}

public Node addNodeAfter(Integer element) {
    return link = new Node(element, link);
}

public String toString() {
    String msg = "";
    try {
        if (link == null) {
            msg = data + " null in tail";
        } else {
            msg = data + ", " + link.toString();
        }
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        // System.err.println("shit happened here");
    }
    return msg;
}

public Integer getData() {
    return data;
}

public Node getLink() {
    return link;
}
```

Comment: It's easier to guide you if your provide your code or stack trace.

Comment: I edited my post so the my Node class is provided

Comment: try this and check back with us: `String toString(int index) {...}`, the recursive call would be `link.toString(index - 1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped so immensely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method `toString(int i)` which takes as argument the number of elements which still have to be printed. If the argument is larger than zero and there is a valid link, then recursively call the `toString(i - 1)` method with `i` decreased by one:

**Code:**

```
public class Node {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node linkedList = new Node(1, null);
        Node node = linkedList;
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; ++i)
            node = node.addNodeAfter(i);
        System.out.println(linkedList.toString(5));
    }

    public String toString(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            if (link == null)
                return data.toString();
            else
                return data.toString() + " " + link.toString(i - 1);
        } else
            return "";
    }

    protected Integer data;
    protected Node link;

    public Node(Integer data, Node link) {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Node addNodeAfter(Integer element) {
        return link = new Node(element, link);
    }

    public Integer getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getLink() {
        return link;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Seems correct.  I'd prefer to see `data.toString()` rather than `"" + data`

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfectly! You have my axe sir/ma'am!
http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/49727494.jpg

Comment: @user3688675  If Neils answered your question to your satisfaction, you should accept his answer (i.e., click on the checkmark).

Comment: @PaulHanbury (kinda new here) Thanks for the advice! Will do

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend the LinkedList class and override the toString() method, and then use your subclass.

Something like this:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> extends LinkedList<E> {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer("[");
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            out.append(get(0).toString());
            out.append(" ");
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
}
```

And test it like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> myList = new MyLinkedList<String>();
        myList.add("one");
        myList.add("two");
        myList.add("three");
        myList.add("four");

        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```